# Create list of DataFrames 'list index out of range'

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a list of files `[file1,file2...]` and I want to create a list of dataframes of each file. 
I tried the code:

```py
df_list = [pd.read_csv(file, sep=';', index_col=False) for file in file_list]
```

I also tried:

```py
df_list = list()
for file in file_list:
   df_list.append(pd.read_csv(file, sep=';', index_col=False))
```

In both cases I get the error:
`IndexError: list index out of range`

If relevant: There are about 400 files and each file is about 100000 rows. Maybe it's a memory problem?

Comment: It should be, try working witn only first 2 files - `df_list = [pd.read_csv(file, sep=';', index_col=False) for file in file_list[:2]]`, or use `dask`

Comment: Works so it's a memory problem. Do you know why? I iterate over each file and overwrite the dataframe from the previous one. Dask works just fine by the way

Comment: hmmm, I think pandas need big RAM if working with large data.

Comment: however the output with dask is chaotic.